# python3 recursion based on tree structure

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tree

I have the code with recursion function:

```
def myPermutation (newString, newDict):
if sum(newDict.values()) == 0:
    print(newDict)
    return
else:
    curDict = newDict
    nextDict=newDict
    for char in newString:
        # print('from line 09 -> ', curDict)
        # print('from line 10 -> ', char, curDict[char])
        if curDict[char] == 0:
            continue
        else:
            # print(char)
            print(curDict)
            nextDict[char] -= 1
            print(nextDict)
            myPermutation(newString, nextDict)
            nextDict=curDict
    return

newString = 'AB'
# newDict = curDict(newString)
newDict = {'A': 1, 'B': 1}
# print(newString, newDict)
test = myPermutation(newString, newDict)
# print(test)
```

My out put is this:

{'A': 1, 'B': 1}
{'A': 0, 'B': 1}
{'A': 0, 'B': 1}
{'A': 0, 'B': 0}
{'A': 0, 'B': 0}

It looks like my recursion function is not working correctly, I did some debug and found when the function tried to do second loop from top level, (move from 'A' to 'B' from 1st level of Tree), the dictionary changed from {'A':1, 'B':1} to {'A':0, 'B':0}. The expect output put should be something like:

{'A': 1, 'B': 1}

{'A': 0, 'B': 1}

{'A': 0, 'B': 1}

{'A': 0, 'B': 0}

{'A': 0, 'B': 0}

{'A': 1, 'B': 1}

{'A': 1, 'B': 0}

{'A': 1, 'B': 0}

{'A': 0, 'B': 0}

{'A': 0, 'B': 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
curDict = newDict
nextDict=newDict
```

creates two names that both point to the same object. If you change one, the other will change. Maybe you want a deep copy?

```
import copy
curDict = copy.deepcopy(newDict)
nextDict = copy.deepcopy(newDict)
```

This means you can now change the two `curDict` independently of `nextDict`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is great !